# how to create a session and role based access using zk framework

Tags: java, session, zk

I am using MVC and MVVM for my zk framework 6.5 application. Now i want to create and maintain a session in my application but i wasn't find a good example how to create and maintain the session in zk without using spring security.

I have a login page, I know I can get the userName and password and move the user to home page. But that's not what i want. I want to create and maintain a session here and also add user related data in the session so that i can use that in the application anywhere.

I read the following guides
[Implementing ZK MVC](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Essentials/Handling_the_Login_Process_using_ZK_MVC_and_Sessions/Implementing_ZK_MVC)
[Managing Credentials using ZK Sessions](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Essentials/Handling%20the%20Login%20Process%20using%20ZK%20MVC%20and%20Sessions/Managing%20credentials%20using%20ZK%20Sessions)

But i wasn't able to get my concepts straight here.

It would be helpful if you give me some example using actual code.

Currently I have login page and on it's submit buttons with empty fields i am just redirecting the user to home page.

A MVC pattern would be great. I have read zk mvc and UserCredentialManager docs. But i am not sure, how to use this information.

Please also share best practices for zk and design without spring security.

Looking forward to hear a solution from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking to store information in a user's session, this is easy with ZK:

```
Session session = Sessions.getCurrent();
session.setAttribute("my_stored_data", myStoredData);
```

...

```
Session session = Sessions.getCurrent();
Object myStoredData = session.getAttribute("my_stored_data");
```

The `Session` automatically exists for every user and is maintained by ZK for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am implementing shiro with zk, but in My AutheListener of shiro I am not able to get ZK sesion by writing `Sessions.current` , it gives me `null`

Comment: Your authentication listener is probably upstream of the ZK framework, so the session isn't available yet. The same would happen trying to, say, access a user's session in a Spring request filter, for example. In a filter, you have access to the HttpRequest which has a `getSession` function. In your Shiro listener, however, you have no such parameters. This makes it seem like you're trying to do something outside the scope of an `AuthenticationListener`. Maybe reassess why you need the user's session at this stage.

Comment: PS: This is another question, not a comment. Post a new question, I won't be responding to further questions in the comments.